# How to fit an image to imageview height in Android?

Tags: java, android, image

I want to do some image viewer (sorta) app and I'm using viewpager for navigation between images. The images all have dimensions of 1260x2038 and is in the res/drawables directory. What I want to do:

1. In portrait mode, the image will fit with the device height
2. In landscape mode, the image will fit with the device width and is scrollable vertically.

Because I understand that large images can cause out of memory exceptions, I set it so that if the device height is more than or equal to 1920px, I want to image maximum height to be 1920px.

I tried putting the imageview inside a scrollview for these to work and they work don't work like what I expected.

This is what the relevant part of my code currently looks like,

**fragment_page.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentPage.java**

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ScrollView scroll;
    private ImageView image;
    private int imageId;
    private int deviceWidth,deviceHeight;
    private static double ratio = 0.61825;
    private static double ratio2 = 1.61746;

    private static LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollPortraitParams   = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    private static LinearLayout.LayoutParams scrollLandscapeParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    private static ScrollView.LayoutParams imagePortraitParams      = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    private static ScrollView.LayoutParams imageLandscapeParams     = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        imageId = getArguments().getInt("IMAGE_ID");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        scroll  = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        image   = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        deviceWidth  = size.x;
        deviceHeight = size.y;

        loadImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        deviceWidth  = size.x;
        deviceHeight = size.y;

        if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            MainActivity.isInPortraitMode = true;
            loadImages();
        }
        else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            MainActivity.isInPortraitMode = false;
            loadImages();
        }
    }

    private void loadImages()
    {
        if(MainActivity.isInPortraitMode)
        {
            scroll.setLayoutParams(scrollPortraitParams);
            image.setLayoutParams(imagePortraitParams);

            if(deviceHeight >= 1920)
            {
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                     .load(imageId)
                     .override(1187, 1920)
                     .fitCenter()
                     .into(image);
            }
            else
            {
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                     .load(imageId)
                     .override(deviceWidth, deviceHeight)
                     .fitCenter()
                     .into(image);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(deviceWidth >= 1920)
            {
                scroll.setLayoutParams(scrollLandscapeParams);
                image.setLayoutParams(imageLandscapeParams);
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                     .load(imageId)
                     .override(1187, 1920)
                     .fitCenter()
                     .into(image);
            }
            else
            {
                scroll.setLayoutParams(scrollLandscapeParams);
                image.setLayoutParams(imageLandscapeParams);
                Glide.with(getActivity())
                     .load(imageId)
                     .override(deviceWidth, (int)(deviceWidth * ratio2))
                     .fitCenter()
                     .into(image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try to set imageView scaleType to centerCrop. `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`